How to build a Set in C# that compares items only by reference equality, instead of HashCode used by HashSet?
For example, what if I want to have a set of strings with different references, allowing them to have the same values?
String s1 = "String1";
String s2 = "String1";
Console.WriteLine("s1 = s2: {0}", Object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2));
Console.WriteLine("{0} interned: {1}", s1,
                  String.IsNullOrEmpty(String.IsInterned(s1)) ? "No" : "Yes");

String suffix = "A";
String s3 = "String" + suffix;
String s4 = "String" + suffix;
Console.WriteLine("s3 = s4: {0}", Object.ReferenceEquals(s3, s4));
Console.WriteLine("{0} interned: {1}", s3,
                  String.IsNullOrEmpty(String.IsInterned(s3)) ? "No" : "Yes");

// The example displays the following output:
//       s1 = s2: True
//       String1 interned: Yes
//       s3 = s4: False
//       StringA interned: No

I need to have s3 and s4 to be recognized as different objects and exist in the same Set simultaneously, even if they have the same value. In contrast, s1 and s2 should be only present once, because they have the same reference.
But it is not only a problem of strings. How to have a Set for any generic type that only compares reference equality?

Just to be sure could you clarify your use case?

"allowing them to have the same values?" You want a simple List? Your question is highly unclear. Please state more exactly what you want.

Strings are manage in a internal pool to manage duplicate so you don't have to manage this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-string-intern

Because of String Interning, which can happen at any time, I don't think it's a good idea to assume that String values will maintain reference-identity indefinitely.

@Sweeper I think your answer should be undeleted, as ReferenceEqualityComparer is only available on .NET 5+

@Charlieface I deleted it because EqualityComparer.Create is available on .NET 8+. I have undeleted and changed it to a plain old class implementation of IEqualityComparer<object>.

You can use ReferenceEqualityComparer for this purpose but be warned if you use it for string, you may have issue with reference due to how they are handled internally like the comments said.
var s1 = new string("Hello");
var s2 = new string("Hello");
var s3 = new string("Hello");

Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2)); // false
var hashset = new HashSet<string>(ReferenceEqualityComparer.Instance)
{
    s1,
    s2
};

Console.WriteLine(hashset.Count); // 2
Console.WriteLine(hashset.Contains(s1)); // true
Console.WriteLine(hashset.Contains(s3)); // false


You can pass your own IEqualityComparer<string> into the HashSet constructor, and the set will use that to determine equality.
You can create a IEqualityComparer that solely compares object references like this:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class ReferenceEqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<object> {
    public new bool Equals(object? a, object? b) => object.ReferenceEquals(a, b);
    public int GetHashCode(object? o) => RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(o);
    private ReferenceEqualityComparer() {}
    public static readonly ReferenceEqualityComparer Instance = new();
}

Then you can create a set:
var set = new HashSet<string>(ReferenceEqualityComparer.Instance);
var x = "xx";
var y = "x";
set.Add(x);
set.Add(y + y);
Console.WriteLine(set.Count); // 2

